# Set DIV height in percentage and set background image to the same

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am working on a mobile app using `phonegap`. I have 3 div elements, one for header bar and other for tab bar and one more for content. 
  Can anybody tell me how to set div height in percentage and set the background image to the same div element.

Thanks in advance

Comment: paste your code of whatever you have tired so far

Comment: CSS:




.mainview{ 
 margin: 0; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 96%; 
 white-space:pre-wrap; 
 overflow:scroll; 
 background:url(mainview.png);
 }

HTML:




<div class="main view" >
 <input type="text" placeholder="Firstname" />
<div>




I have set the height of other 2 div elements in pixels and it works fine. Only when div height is specified in percentage its height is not getting set .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this css code:

```
#id_div {
  background:url('image.jpg');
  background-size:contain;   /* or this:  background-size: 100% 100%; */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this code.. I could only set width. Still I am not able to set the height. Please note that there are two more div elements whose width I have set in pixels. I want to cover rest of the area with 3rd div element.